# How do i change the texts on a woocommerce product page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have tried to use LOCO TRANSLATE and other research i got from here but none were able to get it

[image]

need help here.

Comment: You'll need to provide a bit more information? The StackOverflow community is here to help with any coding issues you are having, therefore are you using a child theme? What page soecifically is this issue on? Have you tried any coding to fix this concern? Can you update your question to and provide this information?

Comment: I am trying to convert the product page to another language but i couldnt translate the 2 circles above. I used locotranslate plugin to get this done but yet it wasnt changed.

i am looking for the file where i can locate this and change it manually

Comment: I provided an answer below, but I was just doing some research... another option is plugin translation - have a read of this page (https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-localization/). It may provide you with a solution? Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended that you change the core files. Instead if you are using a child theme, you could place this in your functions.php or you can create a plugin... you could use the following code:

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'wpe9123_change_field_text', 10, 3 );
function wpe9123_change_field_text( $translated, $text, $domain ) {
    
    if (is_product() ) {
        
        switch ( $translated ) {
    
            case 'From' :
                
                $translated = __( 'From' ); // Change to your desired text.
                break;
            case 'Choose an option' :
                
                $translated = __( 'From' ); // Change to your desired text.
                break;
        }
        
    }
    
    return $translated;
    
}
```

**Update**
Alternatively, depending on where this screen shot is located, you could try these in place of `is_product()`:

is_product()Returns true on a single product page. Wrapper for is_singular.

**Cart Page**
`is_cart()`
Returns true on the cart page.

**Checkout Page**
`is_checkout()`
Returns true on the checkout page.

Eg: `if (is_product() || is_cart() || is_checkout() ) { ...`

Comment: Have you installed your local translations? Set up WordPress in your language

WordPress needs to be told which language it should run.

Go to: Dashboard > Settings > General and change the Site language.

Go to:  Dashboard > Updates and click on the button to update translations

Once this has been done, the shop displays in your locale if the language file exists. Reference: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-localization/